# Where to write the setup and teardown code for Locust tests?

Tags: python-3.x, load, locust

I've exploring locust for our load testing requirements for Spark but stuck on some very basic tasks; documentation also seems very limited.

Stuck on how/where to write my setup & tear-down code that needs to run only once regardless of the number of users. Tried with below sample given in docs; but the code written under events.test_start doesn't run it seems as I'm unable to use attribute 'sc' anywhere under SparkJob class. Any idea how to access the spark instances created under on_test_start method in my SparkJob class?

```
from locust import User, TaskSet, task, between
from locust import events
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

class SparkJob(TaskSet):

    @task
    def submit_jobs(self):
    # sample spark job

class SparkUser(User):

    host = xxx
    wait_time = xxx
    tasks = [SparkJob]


@events.test_start.add_listener
def on_test_start(**kw):
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName(conn_st['app'])
    sc = SparkContext(master=conn_st['master'], conf=conf)
    #spark = SparkSession(sc)
    return sc

@events.test_stop.add_listener
def on_test_stop(**kw):
    #spark.stop()
    sc.stop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Spark, but making `sc` or `spark` a global variable should work for you. So something like:

```
from locust import User, TaskSet, task, between
from locust import events
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark: SparkSession = None

class SparkJob(TaskSet):

    @task
    def submit_jobs(self):
    # sample spark job
        spark.do_stuff()

class SparkUser(User):

    host = xxx
    wait_time = xxx
    tasks = [SparkJob]


@events.test_start.add_listener
def on_test_start(**kw):
    global spark
    conf = SparkConf().setAppName(conn_st['app'])
    sc = SparkContext(master=conn_st['master'], conf=conf)
    spark = SparkSession(sc)

@events.test_stop.add_listener
def on_test_stop(**kw):
    spark.stop()
```

You can look more into Python global variables. In short, you only need `global` if you're going to assign it or change it, otherwise it should be able to infer the global for you. You can be explicit and add it in each place, though.

Comment: changing it is fine, only reassigning needs global \*nitpicking\* :)